# Adding CSRF tokens to HTTP headers in react/spring boot project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf-token

I've been working on a React/Spring project with the ambition of better understanding spring security and while going fairly successful thus far I've found a shortage of information relating to the handling of CSRF tokens between React and Spring boot. As such, I'm at an impasse.

My question is: How do you add and authenticate a CSRF token between React and Spring Boot on POST requests?

So far I've managed to get the CSRF token into my Cookies (thanks spring) and from there, I've attempted accessing the CSRF token and adding it to my HTTP headers although still receiving 403 responses on POST requests.

My spring security config class contains the declaration enabling CSRF outside of http(`withHttpOnlyFalse()` ).

How I'm trying to access the CSRF token:

I found this online previously for accessing the cookie:

```
  function getCookie(name) {
    if (!document.cookie) {
      return null;
    }
  
    const xsrfCookies = document.cookie.split(';')
      .map(c => c.trim())
      .filter(c => c.startsWith(name + '='));
  
    if (xsrfCookies.length === 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return decodeURIComponent(xsrfCookies[0].split('=')[1]);
  }
```

How I'm declaring HTTP headers:

```
    let csrfToken = getCookie("XSRF-TOKEN");
    console.log("testing csrf token: " + csrfToken);
    const res = await fetch(`/register`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        mobileNumber: mobileNumber,
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }),
    });
```

Any help/support is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this.

Considering the difficulty I had sourcing information here's my solution:

Install the react-cookies library (npm install react-cookies)

Inside of the component which triggers the POST request, declare the following:

```
const cookies = useCookies(['XSRF-TOKEN']);
```

Pass 'cookies' to your function which facilitates the fetch request - For me this was simply called 'signUp' and was called inside my `handleSubmit()` method.

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    signUp(data.get("firstName"), data.get("mobileNumber"), data.get("email"), 
    data.get("password"), setUser, cookies['XSRF-TOKEN'] );
  }
```

My fetch request inside of  `signUp()` looks like the following:

```
    await fetch(`/register`, {
      headers: {
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token,
            "Content-Type": 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(customerData),
    });
```

I'm sure this isn't the cleanest, nor the most practical way to do this and I hope someone is willing to shed further clarity if this is the case.
This was posted on the basis that I struggled to find a solution and hope this may be of some use/help going forwards.